# Canvas Python Не выполняется событие

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
wind = Tk()
var_2 = BooleanVar()
var_2.set(0)
canvas = Canvas(width = 100, height = 100, background = '#FFFFFF')
def draw(event):
       print(1)
       if var_2.get == True:
               x = event.x
               y = event.y
               x1 = x-2
               y1 = y - 2
               x2 = x+2
               y2 = y +2
               canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black')
       
       else:
               print('vr')
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>',draw)
canvas.pack()
c_b_1 = Checkbutton(text  = 'Рисовать', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12), indicatoron = 0, variable = var_2, onvalue =1, offvalue = 0)
c_b_1.pack()
wind.mainloop()
```

Дело в том что draw выполняется, но условие всегда не выполнятся. Для этого я поставил проверку `print('vr')`. Как сделать чтобы условие выполнялось когда нужно. Чекбокс я проверил - всё хорошо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if var_2.get() == True:
```

Надо вызвать функцию.
А еще лучше:

```
if var_2.get():
```

Еще обнаружился такой недочёт[image: недочёт]

Comment: Я знаю просто надо увеличить ширину кисти